# Do something after navigate to another page

Tags: events, windows-phone-7, navigation

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app.

I want to do something after doing this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(destination, UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there any event thrown when a page has navigated to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps...

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
```

http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/03/passing-values-to-windows-phone-7-pages-destination-page-instance-within-onnavigatedfrom-method/